# how to download or read content from google drive files using service account

Tags: google-drive-api, readfile, service-accounts

I am able to list all **files/docs** from the google drive using a service account with the **access token**. **REST API**. **Python** script
and I am not able to download/read content from documents. its throwing error like below.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1LWkJmHqv7lHfdd6qLq8ssdJ99BYeP-9axC
```

Getting file data API URL

```
{
"kind": "drive#file",
"id": "1LWkJmHqv7lHfdd6qLq8ssdJ99BYeP-9axC",
"etag": "\"MTU4NzI4MTM3MzQ2Ng\"",
"selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1LWkJmHqv7lHfdd6qLq8ssdJ99BYeP-9axC",
"webContentLink": "https://drive.google.com/a/dummywebsite.com/uc?id=1LWkJmHqv7lHfdd6qLq8ssdJ99BYeP-9axC&export=download",
"alternateLink": "https://drive.google.com/a/dummywebsite.com/file/d/1LWkJmHqv7lHfdd6qLq8ssdJ99BYeP-9axC/view?usp=drivesdk",
"embedLink": "https://drive.google.com/a/dummywebsite.com/file/d/1LWkJmHqv7lHfdd6qLq8ssdJ99BYeP-9axC/preview?usp=drivesdk",
"iconLink": "https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/16/type/text/plain",
"thumbnailLink": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ydrbZst2W6we3faCPlnYYKluglSTNprdrhEbJjueA5lRgjsqG8FN-Xp0Zqyy68H_XOTEWi2yQlU=s220",
"title": "hello.txt",
"mimeType": "text/plain",
"labels": {
    "starred": false,
    "hidden": false,
    "trashed": false,
    "restricted": false,
    "viewed": true
},
"copyRequiresWriterPermission": false,
"createdDate": "2020-04-17T20:34:32.643Z",
"modifiedDate": "2020-04-19T07:29:33.466Z",
"modifiedByMeDate": "2020-04-17T20:34:30.000Z",
"lastViewedByMeDate": "2020-04-18T20:09:44.394Z",
"markedViewedByMeDate": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
"version": "5",
"parents": [
    {
        "kind": "drive#parentReference",
        "id": "1ccTLIrnwkbTZxUoUavCIwCmz5c68Rymi",
        "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1LWkJmHqv7lHfdd6qLq8ssdJ99BYeP-9axC/parents/1ccTLIrnwkbTZxUoUavCIwCmz5c68Rymi",
        "parentLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1ccTLIrnwkbTZxUoUavCIwCmz5c68Rymi",
        "isRoot": false
    }
],
"downloadUrl": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1LWkJmHqv7lHfdd6qLq8ssdJ99BYeP-9axC?alt=media&source=downloadUrl",
"userPermission": {
    "kind": "drive#permission",
    "etag": "\"Oui67PMpWNMX2al1jEJ17kn5eZg\"",
    "id": "me",
    "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1LWkJmHqv7lHfdd6qLq8ssdJ99BYeP-9axC/permissions/me",
    "role": "owner",
    "type": "user"
},
"originalFilename": "hello.txt",
"fileExtension": "txt",
"md5Checksum": "8ed250d6af95636c70b3ed064260246e",
"fileSize": "4",
"quotaBytesUsed": "4",
"ownerNames": [
    "Balasubramanian V"
],
"owners": [
    {
        "kind": "drive#user",
        "displayName": "Balasubramanian V",
        "picture": {
            "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiIt3jyOQ6VYF0XK_RjwnFTihxnXHOTzzRlaXlRrETHSP79k3XpKMVpX5ZctbtDdThSt_8cxbr2TKWf-BkHe7DzzIyYD4Pz0Et8G_lPv0t7Vk63-sh_JSAZIh6OJbUqzvNh3721AEhxd3wqVMAZT1ux8QIbsMaOrHaSLqGut1XTmqbKUyhfUiLRKUZWTtEb3ZFsggG5G6T-zyxITU65HuXZX5f5pQwoKSf8hyRHIeJBR04ofxltrV6v5jRteBaHUB8ZS6MUe_Gw1Lar4hVTNW5Cy5vAu-b9elgLSvtqNLC9RGP_U0ILlBemgj72rtz2WBzPoeoiRZum_2uASihttAISspHq1L4Ks5L_KFZ2O80YPZ4mfVdywn1L4jlQf0uAXIEhe2jlEjyPf1eQ2LrsrA1ApkxgXkwNSHPvjU4fUcXNpefucf9TrNIX8VRbu4DPHKT8C3EdqpFx5dQLh-m7EvJE1H0TTZ5nY6mhHfFebeC14W22uk95Tg953y9M1PDiYyIC-hlcNLUWSeOx3CBzCMGAAaUfQqO5fyvOU-3gAENPO1qdPnurPdEsuH5csDx6tuyMZSHcGOPTR_5FHp6rcQ-gjtahI0pHqB27Bt0aeg7JuTG4vSA7v7ru6DK6Rb73jP0rEoDztNW72K-CqtpLjM4kGn30ZhaLM8qHNbiD_zGjZT5_8oldj6ad4eKn_DrQuC51vDEIzyrYwkEf_E9wBR7rlVUiWIqsFHBALIyw9z_aW3122BAdePAvotGQ3vlrGjRXTw=s64"
        },
        "isAuthenticatedUser": true,
        "permissionId": "02978886251107598035",
        "emailAddress": "info@dummywebsite.com"
    }
],
"lastModifyingUserName": "Balasubramanian V",
"lastModifyingUser": {
    "kind": "drive#user",
    "displayName": "Balasubramanian V",
    "picture": {
        "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiIt3jyOQ6VYF0XK_RjwnFTihxnXHOTzzRlaXlRrETHSP79k3XpKMVpX5ZctbtDdThSt_8cxbr2TKWf-BkHe7DzzIyYD4Pz0Et8G_lPv0t7Vk63-sh_JSAZIh6OJbUqzvNh3721AEhxd3wqVMAZT1ux8QIbsMaOrHaSLqGut1XTmqbKUyhfUiLRKUZWTtEb3ZFsggG5G6T-zyxITU65HuXZX5f5pQwoKSf8hyRHIeJBR04ofxltrV6v5jRteBaHUB8ZS6MUe_Gw1Lar4hVTNW5Cy5vAu-b9elgLSvtqNLC9RGP_U0ILlBemgj72rtz2WBzPoeoiRZum_2uASihttAISspHq1L4Ks5L_KFZ2O80YPZ4mfVdywn1L4jlQf0uAXIEhe2jlEjyPf1eQ2LrsrA1ApkxgXkwNSHPvjU4fUcXNpefucf9TrNIX8VRbu4DPHKT8C3EdqpFx5dQLh-m7EvJE1H0TTZ5nY6mhHfFebeC14W22uk95Tg953y9M1PDiYyIC-hlcNLUWSeOx3CBzCMGAAaUfQqO5fyvOU-3gAENPO1qdPnurPdEsuH5csDx6tuyMZSHcGOPTR_5FHp6rcQ-gjtahI0pHqB27Bt0aeg7JuTG4vSA7v7ru6DK6Rb73jP0rEoDztNW72K-CqtpLjM4kGn30ZhaLM8qHNbiD_zGjZT5_8oldj6ad4eKn_DrQuC51vDEIzyrYwkEf_E9wBR7rlVUiWIqsFHBALIyw9z_aW3122BAdePAvotGQ3vlrGjRXTw=s64"
    },
    "isAuthenticatedUser": true,
    "permissionId": "02978886251107598035",
    "emailAddress": "info@dummywebsite.com"
},
"capabilities": {
    "canCopy": true,
    "canEdit": true
},
"editable": true,
"copyable": true,
"writersCanShare": true,
"shared": true,
"explicitlyTrashed": false,
"appDataContents": false,
"headRevisionId": "0B_QZJ9jWm1W-OXZCZEpkOG1HT2Q4alBrWmRPdDI4aXNQWnI4PQ",
"spaces": [
    "drive"
]
```

}

API URL:     `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1LWkJmHqv7lHfdd6qLq8ssdJ99BYeP-9axC/export?mimeType=text/plain`

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "fileNotExportable",
                "message": "Export only supports Google Docs."
            }
        ],
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Export only supports Google Docs."
    } }
```

I don't want to download documents through browser auth. I need it through the server-side automatic download and reading process.

All the online guides are giving web download options only.

Please help me.

Comment: Your error message indicates you're trying to export a non-Google Doc.  Have you tried using `get()` instead of `export()`?

Comment: the method get() to retrieve the webContentLink from drive. its not working with access_token from server side.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you just want to download the files. If that is the case you just should use the method [`get_media()`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.files.html#get_media).

If you are not using the library just add `?alt=media` to your request and that should download the file instead of the metadata.

Here is an example that has worked for me right now.

```
GET /drive/v3/files/<file_id>?alt=media HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 0
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
```

---

From the official google documentation on [downloading files in Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_file_stored_on_google_drive).

> To download a file stored on Google Drive, use the files.get method with the ID of the file to download and the alt=media URL parameter. The alt=media URL parameter tells the server that a download of content is being requested.